# Making input.getText take my next input rather than my last one

Tags: java, calculator

I've got a window (like a command prompt) and when I type "calculate", it's supposed to begin the calculator process. When I type "calculator", it says "calculator activated" and "please input your first value".

The problem is, when I type this value, I don't know how to make it use it. Instead, it's taking the text from when I said "calculate" before.

Any ideas of how I can get it to take the number, rather than the word "calculate"?

```
public void calculate(){
    try{
        print("calculator activated" + "\n" + "please input your first value" + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));

        String words = input.getText();
        //trying to get it to take the number I input

        print (words +"\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
        //this print is to test what text it's saving as the 'words' variable
        //all it prints is the word 'calculate'
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the invitation to type a number and reading the content of the input immediately after. So yes, the input at that time still contains "calculate". Printing an invitation, or calling getText() on a text field, don't block until the user erases the text and replaces by something else. It just returns the current text in the field.

GUI applications don't work like console applications. They are event based. Your calculate method should not do anything other that printing the invitation. You should have an ActionListener on the text field or on a button, so that, when the user types enter in the text field or presses the button, the listener is called, and gets the text from the text field.

Read the [tutorial about events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).